# Inline Editing within UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift

I’m trying to build an app that uses UITableView and UITableView Cell.

I want users to tap an Add button to add an item to the TableView without calling up a new window or an alert pop-up. I also want users to tap a cell to edit its value and then save it.

I’m struggling to find the best way to do this. Based on what Apple documents about UITableViewCell, it doesn’t seem possible.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: You're asking how to do a bunch of different things. What have you done so far? Can you display a table from an array of strings? Can you create an "Add" button connected to an action func? Can you create a custom cell with a text field?

Comment: Right now, I have a TableView with an Edit and Add button on top. Once I tap Add, an alert box will pop up asking me to enter an item. I didn't code any logic to display the item I add to the TableView yet, because I don't want to stick with this design.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example.

In your Storyboard, add a `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Set the Custom Class of the table view controller to `SampleTableViewController`. That's all you should need to do to run this.

The table starts out empty. Tap the Add ("+") button on the navigation bar to add a new item to the data array and reload the table.

As you edit a text field, the text will be passed back to the controller via a "callback" closure, where we update the data array with the new string.

There is also a Done button - tapping it will simply `print` the data array to the debug console so we can see the changes. That is where you'd do something like save the user entered data (or whatever else you're planning to do with it).

---

**SampleTableViewController class**

```
class SampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var myData: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // cells will have text fields, so we want to be able to
        //  dismiss the keyboard by scrolling the table
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        // register our custom cell
        tableView.register(SampleTextFieldCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        // put system Add "+" button and system "Done" button
        //  on right side of the navigation bar
        let addBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(self.addButtonTapped))
        let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [doneBtn, addBtn]
    }
    @objc func addButtonTapped() -> Void {
        // add a new element to data array
        myData.append("")
        // reload the table
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    @objc func doneButtonTapped() -> Void {
        // do something with the added / edited items
        //  maybe save then to a database?
        // for now, just print the data array to the debug console
        print(myData)
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SampleTextFieldCell
        cell.theTextField.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        // set the "callback" closure so we can save the text as its being edited
        cell.callback = { str in
            // update data array when text in cell is edited
            self.myData[indexPath.row] = str
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

---

**SampleTextFieldCell class**

```
class SampleTextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let theTextField = UITextField()
    
    // closure used to tell the controller that the text field has been edited
    var callback: ((String) ->())?
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        theTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        theTextField.placeholder = "Enter new item..."
        theTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theTextField)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        theTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldEdited(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    @objc func textFieldEdited(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void {
        // send newly edited text back to the controller
        callback?(textField.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Caps6160 - if that answered your question, be sure to mark it as Accepted for the benefit of other folks who may come across it.